# How do I break line sequence of images on Reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap to make this column of 3 elements, and I don't know how to renderize my fourth element downside my first (breaking the line). I already tried to adjust my width and that happens: the element goes away forward infinite.

Here is the code of my black div, which I'm trying to make to hold all of the elements created (max: 3).

```
<div className="align-items-center bg-dark">
```

[image: problem]

The another divs (sons) are being renderized as list-inline and list-inline-item.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Reactstrap, but I think the names "list-inline" and "list-inline-item" suggest that these components are "inline" components and are always placed next to each other.

Comment: @Daniel you need to provide more code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example